# Yoast meta description character limit

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm new to WordPress and I would like to limit the character length of the meta description input field in the Yoast plugin. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
function mike_description_yoast( $str ) {
 return substr($str, 0, 165);
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'mike_description_yoast' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer microb14, what I'm looking for is when a user types in the meta description field for a page or a post we need to limit the characters provided by the user similar to the post title limit plugin.